# Flex profiler isn't showing me what I expect... Am I doin' it wrong?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, profiling

I'm trying to profile the performance of my Flex code, but I'm not getting the results I expect: the wall clock says that my application **takes about 30 seconds to load**, but when I sort the profiling* results by cumulative time, the **numbers don't add up**: there is one method, `[enterFrameEvent]`, which has a **cumulative time of ~8000ms**, then a bunch of methods with an insignificant cumulative time:
[screenshot of profiling output http://img.skitch.com/20090728-j1rpxigiceutjw955j35sm74ag.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090728-j1rpxigiceutjw955j35sm74ag.jpg)

But even summing up the *cumulative* timesª leaves ~15 seconds unaccounted for.  **Where did that time go?** Is there something I'm obviously doing wrong?

For a bit more background on my application: the load time is a direct result of **data received** from an HTTP service. A request for the data is made in the `Application`'s `creationComplete` handler (the selected row), and **when the data arrives from the server** it is processed recursively. The methods which do the processing (including the result handler) do appear in the profiler's list of methods, but they have an insignificant runtime (~30ms).

*: I'm profiling by clicking the little "Profile" button in FlexBuilder, letting the application start, then clicking "performance snapshot" button.  I've also tried sending the requests in response to a button click: starting the application using the profiler, clicking the "performance snapshot" button, clicking the button (to request the data), waiting for ~30 seconds while the data is processed, then clicking "performance snapshot" again. The results were similar.

**Edit**: More information: when I say "loading" I mean "my browser is locked up and doesn't respond to anything until it's done". Also, running a memory profile doesn't show anything too unexpected (there is a spike as the application starts, but no significant allocations after that).

**Edit 2**: Some printf debugging has shown me that, in fact, it is not my result handlers which are taking up all the time – it is something else that executes after they have finished.

ª: yes, I realize this is an entirely nonsensical measurement... But I'm trying to make a point.

PS: Sorry for the terrible JPGification... Skitch doesn't do PNGs :'(

Answer (score 1):

Alright, problem solved.

It turns out that setting an mx:Label's `text` field requires Ω(n²) time (where 'n' is the length of the string). There are some optimizations which make it faster for "sufficiently short" strings, but given a string which is "sufficiently long", you get to do all that wonderful work.

Needless to say, my strings were "sufficiently long".

Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Profiler doesn't consider asynchronous HTTPService call times because there isn't any code running during that time. The runtime is just waiting for the HTTP response.

Use a HTTP tracer plugin like Fiddler or HTTPWatch to measure time taken by HTTP calls. Then the times should add up.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear: the time is spent processing the data my Flex application receives from the HTTP service – not waiting for the service to send data back.